# How Clear, Deselect or Uncheck Dynamic Radio Buttons List?(ASP.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, html, webforms

I created Radio Buttons List of dynamic way. Using HTML tags, I employed the DIV tag in a couple of RadioButtons, this leave one choice or one election (working like a GroupBox). Also, I created a Clean Button that going to clean or deselect the RadioButtons List. I proved that use of Clean() method not works. And using the ID of Radio (equals to "false") also not works. Por example:

```
protected void btnLimpiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
   this.RadioButtonList0_1.Checked = false;}
```

I need know how to clean these dynamic controls that were created through consult in SQL. Here genre the Radio Buttons list:

```
foreach (DataRow drCurrent in objDataTable.Rows){
   HtmlGenericControl createDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
   createDiv.ID = "divA" + i;
   createDiv.Style.Add("float", "left");
   createDiv.Style.Add("padding", "2%");

   RBL = new RadioButtonList();
   RBL.ID = "RadioButtonList" + i.ToString(); ;
   RBL.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
   RBL.Items.Add("Si");
   RBL.Items.Add("No");
   RBL.Items[0].Selected = false;
   createDiv.Controls.Add(RBL);
   i += 1;
 }
```

The previous, works successful. But ¿What is the method, function or code that make this action? 
However, I used a list that count and then search each RadioButtonList and deselect it.

```
foreach (RadioButtonList L_RBL in RBL.Items)
        {
            RBL.Items.Clear();
            L_RBL.ClearSelection();
        }
```

And not working :(
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

RBL shouldn't contain any RadioButtonList objects, as it is itself RadioButtonList.  It will contain radio buttons.

I found this question while looking for help on a similar issue.  This should work to clear the selections on your RBL:

```
RBL.ClearSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code

```
RadioButtonList1.SelectIndex = -1
```